# getUserMedia Android Webview Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera, ionic-framework, getusermedia

I'm trying to do some basic things by getting an Android device's camera stream with getUserMedia. To my understanding, this should be supported on Android Lollipop, which I'm running, but even with permissions set to allow video and audio my request for a media stream is automatically denied.

So I tried using Crosswalk with Ionic, and I can get the media stream. The data is just empty. To my understanding this should be supported. Does anyone else have experience with getting camera video stream data with Cordova / Ionic?

Comment: Have you managed to get the microphone data? Using AudioContext and the ScriptNode to process the data, but the buffer contains all Zeros. Setting the permissions didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that you have RECORD_AUDIO and CAMERA permissions in platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Cordova takes care about necessary permissions for Cordova API and adds them into manifest file, but it doesn't for HTML5 API.

Comment: Hello oaleynik, thank you for this post. My ionic app is also trying to getUserMedia, but after having done all what has been said here, my app on my phone (Android, Nexus5) cannot acquire getUserMedia (I can see it when remotly inspecting from chrome). Could you please help me on this one. It would be very appreciated!

Comment: This worked for me! I also had to programmatically trigger the prompt to accept the permissions otherwise users would have to go to the app settings and do it manually.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer definitely would have worked prior to the changes to Android permissions.  You are now able to request usage of native functions at the time of use (which honestly makes more sense than on launch) so I highly recommend using the [Android Permissions plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions) which will allow you to check and request permissions programmatically and on demand.

For the same use case that is in the accepted answer you would do the following:

```
var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;

var permList = [
  permissions.CAMERA,
  permissions.RECORD_AUDIO
];

permissions.requestPermissions(permList, permCallBackSuccess, permCallBackError);
```

I hope this helps somebody down the road as it saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: Thanks man. In additional, for android 6 it's not enough. Also you need to duplicate permissions in AndroidManifest.xml. Here is my list of permissions: permissions.CAMERA,
                    permissions.MICROPHONE,
                    permissions.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
                    permissions.RECORD_AUDIO,
                    permissions.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT,
                    permissions.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT,
                    permissions.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by the https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-audioCapture

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-audiocapture --save
$ cordova build
$ cordova run android
```

Now the microphone stream can be processed with the `audioContext.createScriptProcessor`.

ps. It seems, that for this feature to work, just the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission is not enough, the plugin uses also `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS`

Comment: I think that's just for AudioContext- I was using my application in the context of WebRTC so the above permissions worked fine for me. This is good to know though!